# JavaFX bidirectional binding of choicebox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, bidirectional

My question is simple, is there any way of making a bidirectional bind between a choicebox's items and an arraylist (that can be added to and removed from, from another class)

My `SettingsService` contains a simple ArrayList containing `User` objects. New items can be added from other classes and places in my application.
If I add a user to this list, how can the new item automatically appear in the choicebox?

Example:

Viewmodel

```
public class ViewModel {
    private SettingsService settings = new SettingsService();
    public final ObjectProperty<ObservableList<User>> userChoiceBoxItems = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ViewModel() {
        userChoiceBoxItems.setValue(FXCollections.observableArrayList(settings.getUsers()))
    }
}
```

View

```
public class View {

    private ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    @FXML
    ChoiceBox<User> userChoiceBox;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        userChoiceBox.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.userChoiceBoxItems);
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: If `SettingsService` just has a regular `List`, not an `ObservableList`, then there is no built-in way to be notified when the list in `SettingsService` is modified. If you are able to modify `SettingsService`, you could either change it to use an `ObservableList`, or fire `IndexedPropertyChangedEvent`s, and then write code to wire those events to the list in your choice box.

Comment: How are you creating the list?

Comment: @James_D Yeah I was creating it from `FXCollections.emptyObservableList()` which was wrong. Changed it to `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` I'll gladly accept your answer if you post it as one :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create a new `ObservableList` as 
`ObservableList<User> tempList = FXCollections.observableArrayList()` 
and add all items to the list as 
`templist.addAll(userChoiceBoxItems)`
 and then bidirectionally bind